# C++ Tokenize String - Not Working

Tags: c++, string, tokenize

I am having trouble tokenizing a string in order to add the substrings to vectors in an iterative loop.

I have this below.

When I run it, I am getting a return value of 1 from this function call, which I'm pretty sure is not accurate.

`serialized.find_first_of(categoryDelim, outterPrev)`

Code

```
void Serialized::deserialize()
{
        std::string serialized = "-1~-2~BK~123|~me|~you|~us|~9|~stuff|~";
        char categoryDelim = '~';
        char elemDelim = '|';

    if (!serialized.empty())
    {
        //Make sure the container is empty
        innerClear();

        //do the work
        std::vector<std::string>::iterator vecIt;
        std::vector<std::vector<std::string>*>::iterator vecVecIt;

        vecVecIt = vecVec.begin();
        vecIt = (*vecVecIt)->begin();

        //int categoryCount;
        //int elemCount;

        size_t innerPrev = 0;
        size_t innerNext = 0;

        size_t outterPrev = 0;
        size_t outterNext = 0;

        //Check to see whether there is another category delimter after the previous
        while (outterNext = serialized.find_first_of(categoryDelim, outterPrev) != std::string::npos)
        {
            //Check to see whether there are more characters or category delimiters after the previous
            while (innerNext = serialized.find_first_of(elemDelim, innerPrev) != std::string::npos &&
                (serialized.find_first_of(elemDelim, innerPrev)+1 < serialized.find_first_of(categoryDelim, innerPrev)))
            {
                //Add the element to the current inner vector
                (*vecVecIt)->push_back(serialized.substr(innerPrev, (innerNext - innerPrev)));
                innerPrev = innerNext + 1;
            }
            //Advance to the next category delimiter and inner vector
            outterPrev = outterNext + 1;
            vecVecIt++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you use wrong condition:

`outterNext = serialized.find_first_of(categoryDelim, outterPrev) != std::string::npos`

mean

`outterNext = (serialized.find_first_of(categoryDelim, outterPrev) != std::string::npos)`

so `outterNext = 1` when `serialized.find_first_of(categoryDelim, outterPrev) != std::string::npos`

I think you should avoid codes like that, it's often cause of many error. Make your code simple, it's good for read and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I borrowed that style from another SO answer. I will avoid that style in the future.